How do I pass keyword arguments when calling @include in an SCSS @mixin?
I have SCSS files that define a "child" mixin that's included by several "parent" mixins in other files. Both parent and child mixins use optional keyword arguments with default values. Now I want to construct the call from parent to child mixin in a way that it re-uses the parent arguments as keyword arguments, to keep the order of arguments in the child mixin flexible and not having to touch all parent mixins if the argument order in child mixin changes. But the SCSS documentation does not mention a syntax for this or if it's even possible.
The following example shows the problem: The child-swatch got a new argument, $border, in the middle and the @include call in the parent-swatch was not adapted. It turns the keyword arguments into positional arguments, making the colors wrong. .highlight should have border:none;color:yellow
@mixin child-swatch( $background: blue ,$border: none, $foreground: white) {
  background: $background;
  border-color: $border;
  color: $foreground;
}

@mixin parent-swatch($background: blue , $foreground: yellow) {
  @include child-swatch($background, $foreground)
}

.highlight {
  @include parent-swatch($background: red);
}


I'm not sure to understand. Your example shows you know how to use named arguments, so why not writting @include child-swatch($background: $background, $foreground: $foreground)?
